# ¿Como acceder a las propiedades de un archivo en laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

estoy intentando acceder a las propiedades de una imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a la mayoria de ellas accedo asi

```
$request->file('imagenarticulo')->getsize()
```

es decir con el get por delante de la propiedad pero a las que tienen guion, no soy capaz de acceder, estoy mirando la documentacion y no doy con el apartado para acceder a estas propiedades,
Concretamente las propiedades son

- Test
- originalName
- mimeType
- size
- error

obviamente podria acceder desde algun metodo php, pero me gustaria encontrar uno de laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leyendo la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests) veo que:

Para originalName:

```
$name = Input::file('imagenarticulo')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Para mimeType:

```
$mime = Input::file('imagenarticulo')->getMimeType();
```

Para size:

```
$size = Input::file('imagenarticulo')->getSize();
```

No encuentro ninguna manera de obtener el atributo Test o Error.

Comment: Estaba mirando solo en la documentacion de la version 5.2, por eso no me salia nada, solucionado entonces.